# Substituting a single line with multiple lines of text

Tags: linux, shell

In Linux what command can I use to replace a single line of text with new multiple lines?  I want to look for a keyword on a line and delete this line and replace it with multiple new lines.  So in the text shown below I want to search for the line that contains "keyword" and replace the entire line with 3 new lines of text as shown.

For example replacing the line containing the keyword,

```
This is Line 1
This is Line 2 that has keyword
This is Line 3
```

changed to this:

```
This is Line 1
Inserted is new first line
Inserted is new second line
Inserted is new third line
This is Line 3
```

Comment: are you intending to replace a specific line number or the line(s) matching "^This is Line 2$"? either one can be done with sed

Comment: The lines matching.  I'm not quite sure how to replace a single matching line with multiple lines as shown with sed.

Comment: I updated original for clarity.

Comment: After looking at sed carefully I discovered sed contains a c option for change current line and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 13):

```
$ sed '/keyword/c\
> Inserted is new first line\
> Inserted is new second line\
> Inserted is new third line' input.txt

This is Line 1
Inserted is new first line
Inserted is new second line
Inserted is new third line
This is Line 3
```

`$` and `>` are bash prompt

Comment: How do you time it so that after an hour has elapsed with no-one answering the question, you manage to submit your answer just a minute ahead of mine!

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me bat-dung crazy b/c `\n` wasn't working.

Answer (score 8):

Create a file, `script.sed`, containing:

```
/keyword/{i\
Inserted is new first line\
Inserted is new second line\
Inserted is new third line
d
}
```

Apply it to your data:

```
sed -f script.sed your_data
```

There are numerous variations on how to do it, using the `c` and `a` commands instead of `i` and/or `d`, but this is reasonably clean.  It finds the keyword, inserts three lines of data, and then deletes the line containing the keyword.  (The `c` command does that all, but I didn't remember that it existed, and the `a` command appends the text and is essentially synonymous with `i` in this context.)

Comment: Can this be embedded into a single bash script? I'd prefer to keep it to one file.

Comment: @flickerfly: Yes, it can be done without the separate file. It is usually easier with the file, though. It depends in part on what's in the lines to be inserted, but if they include text such as `He said, "Don't do it! You mustn't, even for $100."`, handling that in a shell script becomes a real pain (you have to escape some of the quotes, somehow), but it's almost trivial with the separate `script.sed` file. For plain text, simply put all the script inside single quotes. You need the backslashes — `sed` must see them. If you have to use double quotes, you'll need to double up the backslashes.

Comment: Incidentally, [kev](http://stackoverflow.com/users/348785/kev)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9576547/15168) shows how it can be done in a single script, without an extensive discussion of the shenanigans that might be necessary if the replacement text contains quote characters.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using shell builtins too:

```
STRING1_WITH_MULTIPLE_LINES="your
text
here"

STRING2_WITH_MULTIPLE_LINES="more
text"

OUTPUT=""
while read LINE || [ "$LINE" ]; do
  case "$LINE" in
    "Entire line matches this")OUTPUT="$OUTPUT$STRING1_WITH_MULTIPLE_LINES
";;
    *"line matches this with extra before and/or after"*)OUTPUT="$OUTPUT$STRING2_WITH_MULTIPLE_LINES
";;
    *)OUTPUT="$OUTPUT$LINE
";;
  esac
done < file
echo "$OUTPUT" >file
```

Comment: you dont have to set up the strings as variables outside the while-read-case block... they can just be OUTPUT="$OUTPUTyour\ntext\nhere" ... replacing the \n's with actual new lines